# Assert Equals (double, double, delta) Issue

Tags: java, double, assert, epsilon

I am trying to create an assert equals (double, double, epsilon) method.  I created it and for some reason when I run my tester, the method is failing.

```
public static void assertEquals(double expect, double actual, double epsilon){
    totalAssertMethods ++;
    double difference = (Math.abs(expect - actual));
    if (difference <= epsilon){

    } else {
        totalAssertMethodsFailures ++;
        Throwable throwable = new Throwable("Error: Expected X +/-E, found Y");
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I think the problem is, is that the difference between expect and actual in the test is only different from epsilon by approx 0.000001.  Does anyone know how to go about fixing this?

Comment: What are your input values?

Comment: expected = 0.123456 and  actual = 0.1234571

Comment: Doens't that mean your method is actually working? The difference is 0.0000011 (> 0.000001). But this kind of comparison is always very tricky because of rounding errors.

Comment: I want this to fail, I have a counter that counts failed tests, it is expecting four, but it is counting this as a passed test so I am getting an error saying the tests failed is one short.

Answer (score 1):

Try to round off your values to a certain precision:

```
double difference = Math.round(Math.abs(expect - actual) * 100000D) / 100000D;
```

Do the same thing for epsilon also.

```
double finalEpsilon = Math.round(epsilon * 100000D) / 100000D;
```

Comment: Can you share the values of `difference` and `finalEpsilon`?

Comment: difference = -0.0000011  final epsilon = 0.000001

Comment: In the above case the `difference` is -ve and `epsilon` is +ve and hence it will go inside the `if` condition and not the `else`. Try to use `Math.round` to round the results. Solution updated.

Comment: Figured it out, for some reason when I was saving my file, it wasn't over writing my old file, so when I would compile the same error kept showing up.  Sorry for the inconvenience everyone, but thanks for the good advice!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but maybe usefull to others: you can use the assertj `AbstractDoubleAssert` now:

```
assertThat(actual).isCloseTo(expected, Percentage.withPercentage(0.999999));
```